# Dates disappearing while adding class based on date

Tags: jquery, date

Please see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4m70puv6/4/).  (the alerts are just for info.)

While using Chrome, the dates show up like mm/dd/yyyy (empty), but in IE they show correctly until moving on to the next.

The class is correct but the dates disappear.

How can the dates be made to stay?

```
var now = new Date();
alert(now);
$('input[type=date]').val(function(i, v) {
  var myDate = new Date(v);
  if (now > myDate) {
    $(this).addClass('expired');
  }
  alert(myDate);
});
```

I've tried different date formats:

```
<tr id="1">
  <td>
     <input type="date" class="expiration-date" value="12-28-2017" />
     <input type="date" class="expiration-date" value="12/12/2017" />
     <input type="date" class="expiration-date" value="2016-02-21" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.expiration-date {
  color: green;
}

.expired {
  color: red;
}
```

[Updated code](https://jsfiddle.net/4m70puv6/5/) works.  Thank You for the "return v".

Comment: pass `now` as a global variable. `window.now`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

1. The correct format for entering date value in `<input type="date">` tag is `yyyy-mm-dd`. Rest of the formats won't work.

   Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) for documentation.

   > One thing to note is that the displayed date format differs from the actual value — the displayed date format will be chosen based on the set locale of the user's browser, whereas the date value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd.
2. The callback function inside `.val()` should return a value that will be set as the input tag value. In your code, that callback function returns nothing. Try replacing the code with following

```js
var now = new Date();
alert(now);
$('input[type=date]').val(function(i, v) {
  var myDate = new Date(v);
  if (now > myDate) {
    $(this).addClass('expired');
  }
  alert(myDate);
  return v;
});
```